# Не понятен смысл замены символов в строке

Tags: swift

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let oldText = textField.text! as NSString
    let newText = oldText.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string) as NSString
    if newText.length > 0 {
        doneBarButton.isEnabled = true
    } else {
        doneBarButton.isEnabled = false
    }
    return true
}
```

Не понятен смысл замены символов в строке? PS: условие if понятно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смысл замены в том, что Вы получаете `range` и можете что-то с ним сделать для `UITextField`, что-то подменить/подставить.

В данном же примере смысла никакого не вижу, т.к. создаются 2 не особо нужные переменные, производится замена, затем проверка и все ради того чтобы `doneBarButton.isEnabled = true`, если что-то введено.

Легче сделать в таком виде:

1 `IBAction` для `Editing Changed`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2 Включаем/отключаем кнопку:

```
@IBAction func editingChangedForTextField(_ sender: UITextField) {
    doneBarButton.isEnabled = (sender.text!.characters.count > 0)
}
```

Comment: Круто! Спасибо, применил на практике) Только начал учиться и уже эксперементирую с кодом)

Answer (score 0):

Данная функция вызывается как только пользователь ввел символ, в момент вызова функции `oldText` равен прошлому значению (не включает в себя новый символ), далее в переменной `newText` происходит подстановка нового символа в указанный `range`. Ну и далее проверяется длинна нового текста.